# create a new sheet by using macro in excel 2007

Tags: excel

I am just a new beginer and want to create a new spreatsheet by using Macro. i have the code like these.My code did copy the Blank From but the new sheet's width and heigh are different from the origianl one(Blankform) and i want

1. lock the column B6--down and Column I6--down.
2. is it possible i can create a pop window and ask the name of the new sheet and name the new spreadsheet.

It should be simple for most of people here but for me i really hard. So please help.

thanks

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()

Sheets("Blank form").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Blank form").Range("a1:f281").Copy
Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("a1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Blank form").Select
Range("a1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
dim sName as string
Sheets("Blank form").copy after:=activesheet

sname=inputbox("Enter new sheet name")
on error resume next
activesheet.name=sname
if err<>0 then msgbox "Name not valid"
err.clear
on error goto 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. you save me a day. There is one more question, when i copy into a new spreatsheet it does copy everything, but i do not want to copy the first row which has copy button how can i do it.

Comment: Easiest would be to delete that first row and the button after copy. `Activesheet.rows(1).delete`, `activesheet.shapes(1).delete`

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry i have one more question. how can i lock the cell in the new sheet(column B6 till B_last column). i have to do something like protect?

Comment: Recording a macro would help you figure out the code. You need to unlock the range that needs input (`range("A1:A150").locked=false`) then protect the sheet `activesheet.protect`